# Why does my useCallback function cause an infinite loop in my useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function called getContentfulProjectById. It essentially fetches a contentful project by the id passed to it. It exists in a services/useContentful hook.

```
import { createClient } from "contentful";
import {
  setContentfulProjects,
  setContentfulStaff,
  setSelectedProject,
} from "store/actions/contentfulActions";
import { store } from "store/store";

const useContentful = () => {
  const getContentfulProjects = async () => {
    try {
      const entries = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: "projects",
        select: "fields",
        order: "fields.name",
      });
      store.dispatch(setContentfulProjects(entries));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error Fetching Programs:${error}`);
    }
  };

  const getContentfulStaff = async () => {
    try {
      const entries = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: "staff",
        select: "fields",
        order: "fields.staffId",
      });
      store.dispatch(setContentfulStaff(entries));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error Fetching Programs:${error}`);
    }
  };

  const getContentfulProjectById = useCallback(async (projectId) => {
    try {
        const entries = await client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'projects',
            'fields.projectId': projectId,
        });
        store.dispatch(setSelectedProject(entries));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error Fetching Programs:${error}`);
    }
}, []);
  return {
    getContentfulProjects,
    getContentfulStaff,
    getContentfulProjectById,
  };
};

export default useContentful;
```

The component uses the hook useParams to obtain the projectId parameter, passes that to the function which I've invoked through a useCallback function I've named queryForProject and I pass the function and the result of useParams to the dependency array. I then call this function in a useEffect. I pass the queryForProject as a dependency to the useEffect and it results in an infinite loop. If I were to remove the function from the dependency array, I don't see the loop but I see the warning that I need to pass the function as a dependency.

```
  const { projectId } = useParams();

  const { getContentfulProjectById } = useContentful();

  const queryForProject = useCallback(async () => {
    await getContentfulProjectById(projectId);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [getContentfulProjectById, projectId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    queryForProject();
  }, [queryForProject]);
```

Comment: **queryForProject**  is changing identity  because of **getContentfulProjectById** which triggers your **useEffect** hook!  
try wrapping  **getContentfulProjectById** with a useCallback as well (inside **useContentful**)!

Comment: You haven't shown what `useContentful` does, but `queryForProject` gets a new value when `projectId` or `getContentfulProjectById` change, and that runs the effect.

Comment: useContentful is just a custom hook that makes queries for me. I'll update to include the full file. I've omitted the client info as it is sensitive

Comment: I tried wrapping it in a useCallback in useContentful and still got the infinite loop issue

Answer (score 1):

If the queryForProject function should only run once, the code below should be sufficient!

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function queryForProject() {
            await getContentfulProjectById(projectId);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }

        queryForProject();
    }, [getContentfulProjectById])
```

Can you try wrapping the getContentfulProjectById function with useCallback?

```
    const getContentfulProjectById = useCallback(async (projectId) => {
        try {
            const entries = await client.getEntries({
                content_type: 'projects',
                'fields.projectId': projectId,
            });
            store.dispatch(setSelectedProject(entries));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error Fetching Programs:${error}`);
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: It pretty certainly should depend on `projectId` and run whenever that changes.

Comment: That and this useEffect you provided seems to still give the error that I need to provide the getContentfulProjectById to the useEffect

Comment: @CookieMonsta89 Can you try wrapping the getContentfulProjectById function with useCallback?

Comment: @CookieMonsta89 It seems that after store.dispatch, the getContentfulProjectById function is called again, causing the useEffect to be triggered again. Please wrap getContentfulProjectById in a useCallback with an empty dependency array.

Comment: So I wrapped it in a useCallback and I still get the infinite loop.

Comment: @CookieMonsta89 Can you open a CodeSandbox for me?

Comment: I tried but it looks like I have to pay for a premium subscription in order to import a private repository

Comment: I also tried wrapping the function with a useCallback but it is still giving the infinite loop. I updated the original post with the new code.

Comment: @CookieMonsta89 It seems like the parent component of the component with useEffect is being re-rendered. Can you check it out? The function itself seems to be fine.